# ExecutorService Submit Method Return NULL

Tags: multithreading, unit-testing, junit, concurrency, mockito

I have Executor Service, and submitting it. It returns Future>. My code as below,

```
for (int i = 0; i < firstSplitFiles.size(); i++) {
            Future<Map<String, AtomicInteger>> result = executorService.submit(new WordCountTask(firstSplitFiles, firstFile.getName()));
            firstFileCounterMap = result.get();
        }
```

I have written Unit testing as below,

```
 @Mock
    private Future<Map<String, AtomicInteger>> firstFileWordCounter;

    @Mock
    private Future<Map<String, AtomicInteger>> secondFileWordCounter;


    when(executorService.submit(new WordCountTask(Collections.emptyList(), firstFile.getName()))).thenReturn(firstFileWordCounter);
        when(executorService.submit(new WordCountTask(Collections.emptyList(), secondFile.getName()))).thenReturn(secondFileWordCounter);

        when(firstFileWordCounter.get()).thenReturn(firstCounterMap);
        when(secondFileWordCounter.get()).thenReturn(secondCounterMap);
FileReadHelper.splitAndReadProcess(firstFile, secondFile, executorService, 21);
```

and my splitAndReadProcess method as below,

```
public static void splitAndReadProcess(File firstFile, File secondFile, ExecutorService executorService, int splitSize) throws
            IOException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException {

        AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(INITIAL_COUNTER_VALUE);
        Map<String, AtomicInteger> firstFileCounterMap = null;
        Map<String, AtomicInteger> secondFileCounterMap = null;

        List<File> firstSplitFiles = splitFile(firstFile, splitSize, atomicInteger);
        List<File> secondSplitFiles = splitFile(secondFile, splitSize, atomicInteger);
        logger.info("Reading File(s) process started!");
        for (int i = 0; i < firstSplitFiles.size(); i++) {
            Future<Map<String, AtomicInteger>> result = executorService.submit(new WordCountTask(firstSplitFiles, firstFile.getName()));
            firstFileCounterMap = result.get(); // NULL RESULT
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < secondSplitFiles.size(); j++) {
            Future<Map<String, AtomicInteger>> result = executorService.submit(new WordCountTask(secondSplitFiles, secondFile.getName()));
            secondFileCounterMap = result.get();
        }


    }
```

I'm getting result as NULL. Is this correct approach or i need to modify something in a way of coding?

Comment: Did you implement the proper `hashCode` and `equals` method in the `WordCountTask` class?

Comment: i don't think so it's required ```hashcode``` and ```equals``` in this case.

Comment: How do you think the matching of the arguments works? `@lotor` mentions in his answer below you pass different objects into the mock and into your behaviour definiton of the mock. If they are not equal, mockito assumes you have not defined any behaviour and returns `null`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like argument matching in your mock fails.

Your mock uses new instance of of WordCountTask (which, in turn, is constructed over the empty list).
You expect the mock to work, having *another* new instance of WordCountTask (constructed over the result of *splitFile* function work, which is unknow in the context)

It is not obvoius why the argument matching should succeed.